# Difference between [slug].vue and [...slug].vue

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3

What is the difference between `[slug].vue` and `[...slug].vue`?

The docs are a bit unclear:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes
compared with

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#catch-all-route

where there is the slug with the three dots `...`.

The three dots version does not appear anywhere else, so I was wondering if this is just a name and it would be just the same like `[$$$slug].vue` or the normally used `[slug].vue` and the only thing that matters is that the name is within square brackets?

Answer (score 2):

They are using [slug] for a single route (e.g. /something), while [...slug] is used to catch all the possible routes (e.g. /something/anything/whatever is still valid)

It uses [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so [$$$slug] wouldn't be considered valid syntax.

Comment: A dynamic route can be nested, not only at the apex. And it's not it's doing some real array destructuring, just a convention so that it's easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic route is for when you have something like `/products/fancy-shoes`, it being `/products/[slug].vue` in that case.

A catch-all route can be used for:

- having an unknown depth in your routes, something like `/answers/user12/user15/user24/user48`, imagine wanting to SSR a discussion on Reddit (usually recursive and with no definite end), you theoretically have no idea how deep it can be
- safety guard, if a user has not landed on any prior routes, he can still arrive on the catch-all endpoint (in case you want something a bit more custom than a super generic 404 page)

PS: this is a very niche use case as you can guess, depending on the type of app you're building, you may never need that. But it's available so that you don't need to hack the config if you one day need it.

---

Internally, it works like this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#Catch-all-404-Not-found-Route